# van der Waals coefficients for helium and neon

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, atomic-radius, noble-gases

The values of the coefficient $b$ for helium and neon are

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
\text{Element} & b\text{ / }\mathrm{dm^3\ mol^{-1}} \\
\hline
\ce{He} & 2.38 \times 10^{-2} \\
\ce{Ne} & 1.67 \times 10^{-2} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
<sup>(source: Atkins & de Paula, *Physical Chemistry*, 9th ed., p 916)</sup>

This doesn't make sense, however, considering that neon should have a larger atomic radius than helium. Why is $b_\ce{He} > b_\ce{Ne}$?

Comment: It's a good question, but please, *always* include the units whenever you are discussing science! It may sound pedantic, but science is not science without units.

Comment: I'm guessing charge-to-volume ratio.

Comment: So you mean if the charge density is higher than the atom would be "tougher" and any particle would therefore bounce back immediately.

Comment: What does that even mean, there is no charge on the atoms.

Comment: I should be careful about the terminology. It should had been "electron density" here

Comment: I suspect this depends very heavily neon's full $2p$ orbital and how this affects the volume actually excluded by the atom. I'd also be skeptical of values you find for van der waal's radii unless you trust the method by which they're found because there are quite a few different ways to get a guess experimentally.

Comment: related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37514/16683

Answer (score 1):

The question intregues me so I looked up the $a$ and $b$ values in Wikipedia on the web page [Van der Waals constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page)). This doesn't answer the question, but adds more data to focus the question.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
\text{Element} & a\text{ / }\mathrm{L^2 \ bar\ mol^{-2}} & b\text{ / }\mathrm{L\ mol^{-1}}\\
\hline
\ce{He} & 0.0346 & 0.0238 \\
\ce{Ne} & 0.2135 & 0.01709 \\
\ce{Ar} & 1.355  & 0.03201 \\
\ce{Kr} & 2.349  & 0.03978 \\
\ce{Xe} & 4.250  & 0.05105\\
\ce{Rn} & 6.601  & 0.06239 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

A plot of the Van der Waals $a$ and $b$ values.
[image]

So is the b value for He high, or is the b value for Ne low ?!?

I also looked up for each element what was listed for the covalent radius and the Van der Waals radius on each elements individual Wikipedia webpage.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
\text{Element} & Covalent\text{ (pm) } & Van~der~Waals \text{ (pm)}\\
\hline
\ce{He} & 28 & 140 \\
\ce{Ne} & 58 & 154 \\
\ce{Ar} & 106±10  & 188 \\
\ce{Kr} & 116±4  & 202 \\
\ce{Xe} & 140±9  & 216 \\
\ce{Rn} & 150  & 220 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: So Is the b value for He high, or is the b value for Ne low ?

Comment: What is the plot for ?

Comment: @MathTheNovice - As the text indicates "A plot of the Van der Waals a and b values [for the six noble gases]." The gist is to look at the curve and decide if the He Or Ne value is out of whack for the trend.

Comment: A coefficient stands for the intereaction between molecules while b for molecule volume (In the interpretation from physics ) and I don't really get how it is related though the plot show a significant correlation between them

Comment: I mean is the straight line appeared by coincidence

Comment: @MathTheNovice - I don't know if helium or neon should be on the curve. The other point is that the "a" and "b" coefficients are not "pure" in the sense that both coefficients depend on both the interaction between particles and the volume of the particles.

Comment: @MaxW Also the value of $a$ is very low for $\ce{He}$ is very low compare to even $\ce{H2}$. The only explanation I can think of is '$imperfection$ of van der Waals equation'.